# Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0, assemblies

I changed some names of namespaces, assemblies in one of existing project (C# and ASP.NET). But when I try to debug it; I get this error.

Could not load file or assembly 'HR' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040).

I have replaced DFI with HR in the code.

Answer (score 1):

If your project compiles, you may be referencing the assembly in a config file. I would check anywhere that you may be using late binding to reference a type. Also check your @Page directives as you may have an assembly qualified type reference that is referring to the old HR assembly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Athens.

I changed names in exsisting application and I also changed assembly name (so there's no old HR assebmly). Also, I don't think so that late binding is responsible for this error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sometime I have got such error and began to research how to resolve it. After all I just have added such attribute to web.config compilation node:

```
<compilation debug="true" tempDirectory="c:\temp" >
```

I hope that this can help and other people.

Answer (score 1):

I also got this terrible error and found a solution for this...

> 1. Right Click on the Solution name
> 2. Click Clean Solution
> 3. Restart
> 4. Goto project Properties >> Build
> 5. Change **Configuration** to **Release**
> 6. Start Debugging (F5)

**1) , 2)**

[image: Right Click on the Solution name]

**4) , 5)**

[image: Change Configuration to Release]

Hope this will help you also.